# Where can I find the missing MediaPlayer.Framework and MessageUI.framework frameworks?

Tags: iphone, xcode, admob

I'm attempting to ad AdMob to an iPhone app as a backup for iAd, unfortunately, I can't follow the documentation.  It's telling me to add the 'MediaPlayer' and 'MessageUI' frameworks, but they don't appear to be present -- I can add a number of other frameworks, but those two are AWOL.

Please note that I can add any number of other frameworks; my problem isn't adding frameworks in general, but those two specific frameworks are AWOL.  They can be added to other projects, just not this one.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the **Frameworks** folder, choose **Add** -> **Existing Frameworks**... then select the ones you want to add.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.  I can go to add -> existing frameworks, and the problem is that the frameworks in question don't exist.  (Also, why wasn't this comment already here?  I could have sworn I added it two months ago)